# Largest possible equal product of two sublists

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, factoring

My 13 year old cousin has given me a question he solved at a math competition. I was trying to solve it myself but was unable to find the way.

The problem is this:

> We have a list of these $9$ numbers - $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$. Remove two of them, sum them, and then add the sum back to the list. (for example by removing $7$ and $9$, the resulting list would be $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 16)$. Now split the list into two smaller sublists, e.g $[1,2,3,4,5] = 120$ and
> $[6,8,16]    = 768$. The product of the numbers of the two sublists, however, must be the same. What is the largest possible product in a sublist?

I was trying to go through integer factorization but I am really unable to even make the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $7$.

Suppose it is not removed. Then it must be in one of the sublists. The product of the numbers in that sublist must be a multiple of $7$. So the product of the numbers in the second sublist must be a multiple of $7$, too. However, the only number among $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ that is a multiple of $7$ is $7$. Hence, the sum of the two removed numbers must be in the second sublist and it must be a multiple of $7$.

Similarly, either $5$ is not removed and the sum of the two removed numbers must be a multiple of $5$, or $5$ is removed.

Let us remove $2$ and $5$, which sum up to $7$. Adding $7$ back, we have $1,3,4,6,7,7,8,9$, which can be split into $1,3,4,6,7$ and $7,8,9$. The product of either list is $504$.

You can check $504$ is the wanted answer.

Comment: +1 If it was a proof-based competition (which doesn't seem to be the case), then you'd need to further substantiate why the max is 504.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks.